# v lookup formula in excel to compare values

Tags: excel-formula

I need  to create a formula to display **Hello** if it finds **HelloWorld** in list of values in excel.If it didn't find that value it should display existing value in that list.

My values are like this :

```
HelloIndia
HelloAustralia
HelloWorld
```

Please suggest

Comment: So if it was not found which of the three would it display?

Comment: Hi Craner ,If its not found it should display  HelloIndia
HelloAustralia
HelloWorld

Comment: Are the three value in one cell or three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple excel function and not go the VBA/Macro route... this will probably be your answer.
(Example assumes list is in cell A1)

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("HelloWorld",A1)),A1,"Hello")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Billy, If helloWorld didnt found it should display other values which is there in list.Please suggest

Comment: I edited mine to show what I interpreted your request to be.  You changed the display of your list from inline to stacked which would be a different formula altogether.  Basically Scott's formula would be the one you want to use for that case with a tweak.

=IF(COUNTIF(A4:A6,"HelloWorld"),"Hello World", A4 & " " &A5 &" "& A6)

If you list is dynamic in length... you will probably need to use vba/macros to get the final display of <value> <value> <value>

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub FindReplaceAll()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace text/values throughout entire workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant

fnd = "Hello"
rplc = "HelloWorld"

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht

End Sub
```

Original source:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/14/find-and-replace-all

Comment: Hey Where I need to add this

Comment: That code won't display 'Hello' if it finds 'HelloWorld'.  It finds 'Hello' and replaces it with 'HelloWorld'

Answer (score 0):

I would use COUNTIF() to find the match:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"HelloWorld"),"Hello",A1)
```

Replace the A1 with what you would like to return if the value is not found in the range.

[image]